# How to split a tuple into multiple columns in dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, tuples

- I would like to get a final dataframe in which the tuple `'key'` is split into two columns, `'hr'` and `'filename'`, respectively.
- I also would like the output of the fit 'a, b, c'= *popt to be split into the three columns a, b, c.
- In the current output dataframe, the last three columns do not contain the correct values. They show the initial a, b, c values, which are the initial guess of the fit. They should instead show the output of the fit ( *popt).

I attach my code, current wrong output, and correct output example. Thank you in advance

```py
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['hr', 'filename', 'a', 'b','c'])
new_df.columns = ['hr', 'filename', 'a', 'b','c']

################### curve fitting ########################################

grouped_df = HL.groupby(["hr", "filename"]) ## this is my initial dataframe

for key, g in grouped_df:

    a = g['NPQ'].max()
    b = g['NPQ'].min()
    c = 0.36

    popt, pcov = curve_fit(model, g['time'], g['NPQ'], p0 = np.array([a, b, c]), absolute_sigma=True)

    print('Estimated parameters: \n', popt))

    ##################### new data frame
    new_row = {'hr': key, 'a':a, 'b':b, 'c':c }
    new_df = new_df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

    print(new_df)
```

This is the wrong output
[image]

An example of the correct output (I simplified it for efficiency):

```
hr      filename      a      b     c 
8     20191129.0     21.22  0.55  0.45
8     20191129.0      ..     ..    ..
8     20191129.0      ..     ..    ..
14.0  20191129.0      ..     ..    ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Extract the keys as `k1` and `k2` instead of `key`, because you do `.groupby` on two columns.
- Then create `new_row` with `'hr'` as `k1`, and `'filename'` as `k2`
- Instead of assigning the returned values to `popt`, you can assign them to `(x, y, z)`.

```py
for (k1, k2), g in df.groupby(["hr", "filename"]):
    ...
    (x, y, z), pcov = curve_fit(model, g['time'], g['NPQ'], p0=np.array([a, b, c]), absolute_sigma=True)
    ...
    new_row = {'hr': k1, 'filename': k2, 'a': x, 'b': y, 'c': z}
    new_df = new_df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```

- Alternatively, `key` is a `tuple` because the `.groupby` is on more than one column, so you can extract the separate values by calling the appropriate index.

  - Create `new_row` with `'hr'` as `key[0]`, and `'filename'` as `key[1]`
- If `popt` is a `list` or `tuple`, then you can assign the appropriate indices to `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'`.

```py
for key, g in df.groupby(["hr", "filename"]):
    ...
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(model, g['time'], g['NPQ'], p0 = np.array([a, b, c]), absolute_sigma=True)
    ...
    new_row = {'hr': key[0], 'filename': key[1], 'a': popt[0], 'b': popt[1], 'c': popt[2]}
    new_df = new_df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```